# Go GORM - BeforeUpdate fields have old values

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a Go application with GORM and I'm trying to hash Users' password fields every time they are updated.

To achieve this I'm using the `BeforeUpdate` hook provided by GORM. The problem that I'm facing is that on the said hook the `Password` field for the user (`u.password`) has the old hashed password value that is already stored on the DB instead of the `newPassword` value that I'm updating it with. So when I hash the password on the hook, I'm really just hashing the the already hashed old password.

My `BeforeUpdate` hook:

```
func (u *User) BeforeUpdate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
  if (tx.Statement.Changed("Password")) {
    bytePassword := []byte(u.Password) // Old password value here!
    passwordHash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword(bytePassword, bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if (err != nil) { return err }
    tx.Statement.SetColumn("password", string(passwordHash))
  }
  return nil
}
```

And the update is triggered like this:

```
var user models.User
err := db.First(&user, id).Error
if (err != nil) { log.Fatal(err) }
// Not sure how to access this "newPassword" value on the "BeforeUpdate" hook
err = db.Model(&user).Update("password", newPassword).Error
if (err != nil) { log.Fatal(err) }
```

**Edit: Working solution thanks to @s3vt's answer**

Just had to change my `BeforeUpdate` hook:

```
func (u *User) BeforeUpdate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
  if (tx.Statement.Changed("Password")) {
    u.Password = tx.Statement.Dest.(map[string]interface{})["password"].(string)
    bytePassword := []byte(u.Password)
    passwordHash, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword(bytePassword, bcrypt.DefaultCost)
    if (err != nil) { return err }
    tx.Statement.SetColumn("password", string(passwordHash))
  }
  return nil
}
```

Comment: suggest: before performing the update operation `user.password = newPassword`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the new password value form the `tx.Statement.Dest` map.
This is the same map that `SetColumn` updates the value to.

OR set the new password value before the actual update call.

```
user.Password = newPassword
err = db.Model(&user).Updates(&user).Error
```

In this case old password will not be available at the hook.

Comment: That worked thank you so much! @s3vt

Could you please link to the documentation of `tx.Statement.Dest`? Couldn't find it anywhere. (I'll up vote your answer when you do, I feel like it's incomplete without the source)

A quick note: Could not solve it by setting the password on the user before the update call because then the change detection (ie: `tx.Statement.Changed("Password")`) wouldn't work.

I'll update my question with the working code using `tx.Statment.Dest`